# blur размывает границы блока

Tags: css, css3

Проблема: при использовании blur происходит размытие нужной мне картинки, но вместе с этим, размывается и граница со скроллом, верхней, левой и нижней части блока и получается плавный переход от белого цвета к картинке. Как избавиться от этого эффекта?

Comment: [mcve] добавь в вопрос в виде сниппета.

Answer (score 2):

Положить картинку в div, которому сделать overflow:hidden.